# How to store timed data points in sql server

Tags: sql-server, time-series

I need to store a list of points in a database (SQL server), and I'm not sure if the option I took is the best solution.

Those data points are very basic, a decimal value, representing the measured value at time t, and a basic timestamp, which is simply an int representing the seconds from the start of the measurement.

In my domain, I have a `Measurement` class that will contain a list of those data points.

What I have now is a `MeasurementValue` table which has

```
MeasurementValue
----------------
TimeStamp INT PK
MeasurementId INT PK + FOREIGN KEY on Measurement
Value DECIMAL
```

One measurement has about 1000 data points, and the number of measurements will probably be in a few hundred I would say, maybe thousand.

I don't really care about being able to query this `MeasurementValue` table, it will always be took as a whole.

I know that the numbers of points that will contain this table is probably small enough to be manageable with this design, but I'd like to know if there is a better alternative in the case where those numbers would grow in the future.

Comment: for the moment I I have one question: I understand that MeasurementId is a FK to another table (Measurement). My question: wouldn't it make more sense to add 2 columns to that Measurement table (TimeStamp and Value) instead of having this separate table?

Comment: I ask the above question since I notice that you have "MeasurementId INT PK + FOREIGN KEY on Measurement" that leads me to the conclusion that the relation MeasurementValue to Measurement is 1-1 and not n-1 (since you have  a PK on MeasurementId and this requires unique values..

Comment: @EduardUta You probably misread, it's a composite key composed of TimeStamp AND MeasurementId. This means that it is an n-1, you can have multiple time stamps linked to a measurement id. You can only not have the same time stamp linked to the same measurement id.

Comment: now I see it, thanks for the reply. No other comments for the moment.

Comment: The design is ok I think. I would just put MeasurementId first in the PK (clustered index really). It feels like you are always going  to access the data via measurement id, but I can be wrong here.

Comment: @TomT, yes the data is going to be accessed only by MeasurementId, it doesn't make sense to access it in another way.

Comment: Gimly, are the points entered in a linear fashion, chronological or are measurements entered in bulk?  the structure of the table could very based on not just how data is being retrieved but being inserted as well.  You wouldn't want SQL to have to expand existing pages because you insert data directly into the middle of a clustered index.  But if the table will only be about 1000 records and you don't care about querying it, then its all a NULL point.

Comment: @BradD Good point, measurements will be entered in bulk. The measurements are saved first in memory where we get all the measurements for one "experiment" and then the user saves the whole experiment at once. So we will save a list of measurements (probably around ~100) with a list of ~1000 measurement points at once.

Comment: Gimly, I don't know enough about the rest of your model to say this for a fact, but my gut is saying that you're missing the FK relationship to the experiment.  You should have an ExperimentID, with a measurementID taken at a specific time as your PK.  Is the experiment baked into the MeasurementID?  Without knowing what the model is really tracking, if you have multiple experiments you could take specific measurements at the same time in reference to the start of the experiment.

Comment: @BradD I've just shown a little bit of the model as to not confuse people. I do have the Experiment table and of course a foreign key from Measurement to it. Basically I'm just wondering if it would be more efficient to keep this `MeasurementValue` table, or store the measurement data as a bulk in a field of the `Measurement` table. Knowing that I will have tons measurement values and I will always save and retrieve those measurement values as a bulk and never really query on them.

Comment: @Gimly Instead of saying "I've just shown a little bit of the model as to not confuse people.", give us more of your model and requirements so that we can understand more of your problem.

Comment: @AtillaOzgur The rest of the model is not really relevant to the question, so that would not make a lot of sense to show it. The `Measurements` are independent one from another, it's not really useful to compare measurement value from a measurement to another measurement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general table design looks fully normalized and fine by me. What range and precision will your decimal values be? The default size of the data type might larger than you require. Check Books online at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx

Technically, every column in a database could be named “Value”. I might change the column name to something more indicative of the actual data.

I would advise against denormalizing your values. Yes, it can speed data retrieval performance (retrieve 1 big row, as opposed to a lot of small rows with the overhead of all those indexing columns), but you’ll then have to parse the blob, so how much time do you actually save? As mentioned, with a delimited list of values you lose the individual timestamps (and you have to worry that you’ve set aside enough space for you delimited *decimal* values), and if you go with XML, why bother with a relational database?

I have no clear answer regarding indexing, just a few design questions.

If you always retrieve all the data from the table when queried, indexing is largely irrelevant (except for primary key enforcement). However, that means you’d want all values for all measurements for all experiments… which seems unlikely.

A planning question: what is the expiration date of your data? Once loaded, does it stay there forever, or will it eventually be deleted from the system? What's fast today in development is often horrible a year later in Production.

Data is being bulk-loaded. Is that data sorted, or in random order? Is loading performance (and potential table locking) critical, or not so relevant?

My knee-jerk reaction is to make clustered index on (MeasurementId, TimeStamp). However:

- Queries (and deletes) on all values for a given measurement will be fast if MeasurementId is the first column
- Bulk loading into clustered indexes is efficient only if the data is already sorted in the index order
- When not sorted, or if data is added later on, you will get page splits and fragmentation. If subsequent modifications are an issue, identifying and setting an appropriate fillfactor will be necessary.
- You might have issues with table locks during bulk loads. If this is a major issue, table partitions might be worth considering.

Comment: Thanks for this very interesting answer! Good point about range and precision, I'll check what we get from the instrument and make sure I'm not storing an over-precise value. The data will most likely stay there forever, or at least a long time, that's the reason why I'm worried about the potential size of that table. Data should be stored by the timestamp. Data loading will be important, but the DB won't be accessed by a lot of concurrent clients (2-3 maximum).

Answer (score 1):

Gimly,
You have two options.  One is to create a table as you've suggested. though you'll probably want to change it up slightly (Though the change is rather important);

Entity-Attribute-Value would look like this;

```
MeasurementID PK FK
TimeStamp PK
Value
```

Some SQL guys are hugely EAV adverse; However, when it makes sense, it makes sense.
This will work fine because you only return your data when you need it. Simply join to the table and call it good.  In this case with small data types like this you're going to be able to fit a ton of rows on a page.  I probably wouldn't worry about a clustered index unless the measurementID row is always inserted sequentially. A Heap with a maintained non-clustered index around the MeasurementID should do just fine.

EDIT-ADDED: The MeasurementID needs to go first in the Index regardless of whether you go clustered or non.  The reasoning is that you want the timestamps to be grouped with the measurement, not measurements grouped with timestamps.  IE Select all timestamps based on measurement not select all measurements based on timestamp.

The other option which will also work, but I suggest you test first, is like you suggested keep your data inline on the Measurement table.  Use XML, you probably don't need to go through and generate a schema file, but it is a way to preserve the relationship inline.

```
MeasurementID, Col1, Col2, col3, MeasurementDetailXML
```

and set the XML column to 
large value types out of row = ON

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189087(v=sql.105).aspx

This will push the large column out of the regular data page.  only select the column when you need it.  There are a number of good articles about XML in SQL, I usually revert to this one;
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345118(v=sql.90).aspx

Your XML might look something like the following;

```
<MeasurementDetail>
  <TimeStamp> </TimeStamp>
  <Value> </Value>
</MeasurementDetail>
<MeasurementDetail>
  <TimeStamp> </TimeStamp>
  <Value> </Value>
</MeasurementDetail>
....
```

There are a number of ways to form the XML document, so use whichever method you feel comfortable.

In practice, don't make this more complicated than it has to be.  I would suggest writing an EAV table just because of ease of development, maintenance and the ability for someone else to pick up the code quickly.

There are a number of RIGHT answers, so go with the simplest unless you prove its not sufficient for the business need.

Answer (score -1):

According to your question and comments, you can choose one of the below.

First one is your normal table design.

```
MeasurementValue
----------------
TimeStamp datetime PK
MeasurementId int PK + FOREIGN KEY on Measurement
Value DECIMAL
```

Choose this one if you are going to query Value column and manipulate it in database.

```
MeasurementValue
----------------
TimeStamp datetime PK
MeasurementId int PK + FOREIGN KEY on Measurement
Value varchar(8000) comma separated int values.
```

Choose this one if you are **NOT** going to query Value column and manipulate it in database.

From your question, second design will be better for you from storage and query speed option. 
Also you can choose to store Measurement Values as difference from last measurement value instead of measurement from start timestamp. see example below.

```
Measurent Values difference  from start timestamp
1,2,10,12,20
Measurent Values difference from last measurement
1,1,8,2,8
```

This will make your Value column even smaller so that varchar(8000) will be more likely to hold everyone of your values.

Comment: So, kind of making a blob for the measurement cell. Why using a CSV for the Value though? Wouldn't it make more sense to use the XML format that SQL supports? What would be the advantage of a CSV?

Comment: parsing CSV is always easier than XML. Almost every programming  language supports some form of following statement "1,2,3,10".split(",")

Comment: Just a note: your second design loses the ability to pair each value with its own timestamp. I.e., you know what the values are, but not when they occurred.

Comment: Yeah, actually this answer is wrong. If done like that, the blob should go into the `Measurement` table, not keeping the `MeasurementValue`table

Comment: @Gimly This design is "what is according to your requirements". Of course you can delete MeasurementValue and get all of its values to Measurement table.